# How to use vimgrep recursively for specific file extensions?

Tags: vimgrep

I'd like to search the current directory recursively for the word under cursor.

Here is what I have now in my .vimrc (Note I'm on Windows):

```
nmap <leader>f :vimgrep! <cword> **.* <bar> :copen <CR>
```

This works fine but it searches all the files including object files, project files, etc.

I want `vimgrep` to search only `.c` `.h` `.txt` files

When I tried the following, it didn't work:

```
nmap <leader>f :vimgrep! <cword> **.c **.h **.txt <bar> :copen <CR>
```

What is the right way to do it?

Another question: why adding `!` after `vimgrep` doesn't prevent it from automatically jumping to the first match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `{}` to specify different extensions:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :vimgrep /<c-r><c-w>/j **/*.{c,h,txt} <bar> :copen <CR>
```

Some suggestions:

- Use `nnoremp` unless you want to recursive mappings
- You may wanto to look into `'wildignore'` to ignore object files and other files which should always be ignored
- You may want to look into faster project grepping tools. e.g. [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) & [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)
- You can use the `j` flag to prevent `:vimgrep` from jumping the first match. e.g. `:vimgrep /foo/j **/*`
- Using `!` with `:vimgrep` will abandon the current buffer when jumping to another buffer. See `:h abandon`.

For more help see:

```
:h :vimgrep
:h 'wildignore'
:h :grep
:h 'grepprg'
:h 'grepformat'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me. Could you please answer my second question too?

Comment: I tried adding `j` flag after `<cword>` but it didn't work. Could you please update the full command with `j` in the right position?

Comment: You need to use the `/` pattern delimiters to use any flags. example: `:vimgrep /<c-r><c-w>/j %`